# mysql - mark all but 1 records matching multiple fields (near duplicates) as deleted

Tags: mysql, sql, duplicates, sql-update, inner-join

I have a mysql table for items in a shopping cart.
I need to mark any duplicates of the same item as deleted (by entering a timestamp in the 'deleted' column, not actually delete for audit trail reasons).

The columns of the table (order_item) are:

```
id (int, primary key)
order_id (int)
type (enum)
item_id* (int)
timeslot_id* (int)
price_id* (int)
created (datetime)
deleted (datetime)
```

I want to update all but 1 of the items in the table that are duplicates (have the same values as another row) for an order on the columns marked with a * to have the current datetime in the deleted column. So that only 1 of the same product can be purchased at a time.

I'm achieving this at present in multiple stages by doing a select query with a GROUP BY and a count on the id and using Concat to get a comma separated list of IDs - then updating those in a separate query.

```
SELECT COUNT(id) AS c, 
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT id SEPARATOR ",") AS ids 
FROM cps_order_item WHERE order_id = "10" 
AND deleted = "0000-00-00 00:00:00" 
GROUP BY type, item_id, timeslot_id, price_id;
```

Any reliable way to do this all in one query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can implement the logic with an update and a self-join:

```
update order_item oi
inner join (
    select order_id, item_id, timeslot_id, price_id, min(id) as id
    from order_item
    where deleted = '0000-00-00 00:00:00'
    group by order_id, item_id, timeslot_id, price_id
) oi1 
    on  oi1.order_id    = oi.order_id
    and oi1.item_id     = oi.item_id
    and oi1.timeslot_id = oi.timeslot_id
    and oi1.price_id    = oi.price_id
    and oi1.id <> oi.id
set oi.deleted = now()
where oi.deleted = '0000-00-00 00:00:00'
```

The subquery computes the minimum `id` for each tuple of values. Then the outer query sets column `deleted` for rows that match on the tuple and whose `id` is not the minimum.

This processes all orders at once. You can add a filter in the `where` clause of the outer query to handle just one order. You can also change the aggregate function to something else if you like (maybe you want `max(id)` instead of `min(id)`).

Comment: Thanks so much @GMB this was so helpful and works a charm (once I remembered that NULL != NULL in mysql comparisons).

Answer (score 1):

Note : This solution **does not** work under MySQL. See comments below. I leave it hoping it may help someone using another RDBMS in the future.

Just delete the items within the same order with a created date after the one you are considering. I'm not exactly sure about the MySQL syntax, but something which looks like:

```
UPDATE order_item o
SET deleted = NOW()
WHERE deleted = '0000-00-00 00:00:00'
  AND order_id = 10
  AND EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM order_item
    WHERE order_id = o.order_id
      AND item_id = o.item_id
      AND type = o.type
      AND timeslot_id = o.timeslot_id
      AND price_id = o.price_id
      AND deleted = o.deleted
      AND created > o.created
  );
```

I used the same constraints as the query you gave.

You may want to remove the `AND ORDER = ID` line to clear all orders at once.

Maybe the constraint on price_id, type and timeslot_id are not necessary (assuming the item id implies these attributes).

Comment: I like this answer as well, but I just want to note that comparing `created` might be risky (e.g. many records added at the same time), that's why I prefer the other answers use of MIN(id).

Comment: You can use `id > o.id` instead of `created > o.created` if you feel it is safer. I'm glad to see your problem is solved anyway :-)

Comment: @FabianPijcke: unfortunately MySQL does not support reopening the target table in the `WHERE` clause (that's the database that I know that has such limitation...). You would need to write this as a `join` query instead.

Comment: I was not aware of this, my bad for not trying to run the query :O Thank you for pointing it out!